# Kony - Unable to store object in Memcache node

Tags: temenos-quantum

I have integrated a simple service call in Kony, When I run my App on iOS simulator i cannot see any errors, instead in the middleware.log files I can see below error, Can anyone please help.

```
   Logs 

X-Forwarded-For=null] 12:15:55,270 DEBUG factory.KonyAppFactory - Memcache is Enabled and Memcache Session Management instance is created
[appID=ProjectBestBuy01
requestID=61c164cc-1743-437f-8288-8e6ec0903d86
UA=BestBuy/1.0 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/15.0.0
rcid=NA
referer=NA
node.no=1
REMOTEADDRESS=127.0.0.1
    REMOTEADDRESS=127.0.0.1
    X-Forwarded-For=null] 11:39:51,112 ERROR cache.MemCacheWrapper - Unable to store object in Memcache node /127.0.0.1:21201  for Key: 10e6351c7-fe0d-44e4-bbc5-3e448d0af7a6 in 3 attempt from Server Node Num: 1
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation
        at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient$OperationFuture.get(MemcachedClient.java:1656)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.cache.MemCacheWrapper.storebyNoofattempts(MemCacheWrapper.java:277)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.cache.MemCacheWrapper.store(MemCacheWrapper.java:235)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.common.AbstractCacheSessionManager.store2Cache(AbstractCacheSessionManager.java:280)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.common.AbstractCacheSessionManager.exit(AbstractCacheSessionManager.java:212)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.common.MemCacheDCFilterAction.doChainDCFilter(MemCacheDCFilterAction.java:115)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.common.MiddlewareMemCacheDCFilter.doFilter(MiddlewareMemCacheDCFilter.java:42)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.common.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at com.konylabs.middleware.common.AddAdditionalResponseHeaderAttribute.doFilter(AddAdditionalResponseHeaderAttribute.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    [appID=ProjectBestBuy01
    requestID=3dc52d1e-9b5a-45d5-8b64-92f8cf1f0cb7
    UA=BestBuy/1.0 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/15.0.0
    rcid=NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question don't have enough information.
1.Are you trying to save any information on middle ware meme cache ?
2.if yes , how  you are trying to save preprocessor,postprocessor or javaservice ?
3.Are you set scope as session in service def. file ?

Comment: do you have any idea why does this error come at first place. i am seeing traces of this error and i really dont mean the exact meaning and impact of it.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. 
this is seems like your are trying to save something into the middleware session (any one of the above 3 options). and your server not properly configured with memcache. if you are using tomcat please check whether you are started memcache.

to check memcache status in linux use following comment
echo status | nc 21201